# C# - Check if the RESULT returned by a linq query on a DataTable has rows

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, resultset

I usually query datatables with linq to filter data such as:

```
var plan = from p in planData.AsEnumerable()
let rnk = p.Field<decimal?>("RANK")
let spd = p.Field<string>("SPEED")
where rnk.HasValue
&& rnk == Convert.ToInt32(rank)
   && spd == speed
select p;
```

where `planData` is a datatable. The problem is that I have no *simple* way of check if the result returns anything. I cannot use any useful methods at all (like `ToList` , `AsEnumerable`) on the `plan` variable. All I can do is try to loop and see if there were anything returned.

Any ideas how I can get around this ? Maybe there is another way to select data from a datatable ?

Comment: try see [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Christos Explanation for why you shouldn't use `plan.Count()>0`. `plan` is a sequence. Assume it has `10000` rows, count will enumerate(loop) all `10000` then checks against 0. Why not use `Any` which checks only first element available or not? alternatively you can use `planData.Count > 0` which is more efficient than `Any`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the inbuilt test:

```
if(plan.Any())
{
   //... do stuff
}
```

you can also use the nice little override on that, to test for the existence of items in Any().i.e:

```
if(plan.Any(x => x.IsValid))
{
   //... do stuff
}
```

wonderful little extension.

**[update]** -include the `using System.Linq;` using also

Comment: I cannot use that one either. I get an error saying there is no such method for `plan` variable.

Comment: System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found

Comment: Ah ok I got it. I needed to import linq manually. It doesnt suggest for some reason

Comment: are you using the `using System.Linq;` using statement??

Comment: thanks! that was the problem. But how was able to write a linq query without using linq ? :)